# Authenticating with a WSDL server with SOAP PHP

Tags: php, .net, soap, wsdl

Ive been asked to authenticate with a WebService that is undocumented, and I have been struggling to get it to work. this is what i have done thus far.

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://x.x.x.x/dispatch/AuthenticationWebService.asmx?WSDL");
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
echo "<br>";
var_dump($client->__getTypes()); 

$a["channelType"] = "x";
$b["userName"] = "a";
$c["password"] = "b";

var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
var_dump($c);

try {
        print($client->__soapCall('Authenticate', array($a, $b, $c)));
} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
        echo $exception;
}
```

this returns:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(59) "AuthenticateResponse Authenticate(Authenticate $parameters)" [1]=> string(59) "AuthenticateResponse Authenticate(Authenticate $parameters)" } 

array(5) { [0]=> string(92) "struct Authenticate { BookingChannelType channelType; string userName; string password; }" [1]=> string(25) "string BookingChannelType" [2]=> string(73) "struct AuthenticateResponse { AuthenticationResult AuthenticateResult; }" [3]=> string(116) "struct AuthenticationResult { AuthenticationError Error; string ErrorMessage; boolean Succeeded; string Token; }" [4]=> string(26) "string AuthenticationError" } 


array(1) { ["channelType"]=> string(3) "Web" } array(1) { ["userName"]=> string(10) "RouteMatch" } array(1) { ["password"]=> string(6) "Rm2012" } 


SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: userName in /var/www/WebService/test.php:76 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/WebService/test.php(76): SoapClient->__soapCall('Authenticate', Array) #1 {main}
```

For the life of me I cannot see why this isnt working? I have tried a few other combinations too..

if i change

```
$a["channelType"] = "Web";
```

to something else, like

```
$a["channelType"] = "junk";
```

then it says...

```
SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document (2, 225). ---> Instance validation error: 'Junk' is not a valid value for BookingChannelType. in /var/www/WebService/test.php:71 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/WebService/test.php(71): SoapClient->__soapCall('Authenticate', Array) #1 {main}
```

This indicates to me that the data is getting passed to the web service, but i dont know why the userName and password are coming back as null??

I also tried:

```
try {
        print($client->__soapCall('Authenticate', array($a, "a", "b")));
} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
        echo $exception;
}
```

To no avail.. it still says that userName is null.

Where am i going wrong??

Comment: Have you tried `$a["channelType"] = "x";$a["userName"] = "a";$a["password"] = "b";` and `__soapCall('Authenticate', $a);` ?

Comment: @1nflktd yeah i have tried that. same error, userName is null.

Comment: sorry @1nflktd I was slightly wrong, doing that it says the first argument is null.. The value of argument 'channelType' (0) is invalid for Enum type 'BookingChannelType'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$SoapCallParameters["channelType"] = "x";$SoapCallParameters["userName"] = "a";$SoapCallParameters["password"] = "b";

try {
        $obj = $client->__soapCall("Authenticate", array('parameters'=>$SoapCallParameters));
        var_dump($obj);
} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
        echo $exception;
}
```

After some investigation, the wsdl web service was a .NET service. which means u needed to add "paramaters" whilst passing the values.